# Proving ${\sim p}\mid{\sim q}$ implies ${\sim}(p \mathbin\& q)$ using Fitch

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am struggling with proving something in Fitch. How can I prove from the premise ~p | ~q , that ~(p & q). Any ideas on how I should proceed?

Comment: Is $\mid$ the [Sheffer stroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke)? Doesn't seem so. Do you mean $\lor$ instead of $\mid$?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is ∨.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll have my first stab at an answer here (I've been won over from Stack overflow- first answer!).

I believe on math.stackexchange it's not tradition to completely give the game away if it's a homework question?

*notation*: noticed you're using single bar for vel, I'll use $\vee$ and "|" to distinguish Fitch hypothesis marks until I can work out math stackexchange formatting.

So,
**Hint**: your last step will be $¬(p \wedge q)$, of course, and obviously your first

1 $(¬p \vee ¬q)$

Then we prove by two classical reductio.
First, on the conclusion

2 | $p \wedge q$

Which gives us

3 | $p$

Then, remember the $\vee$-elim rules (you're working from (1) now): so we assume:

4 | | $¬p$

5 | | $\bot$(by 3)

Well, I'll leave you to fill in the details, but we can do the same for the q side of 2 and 1.

This means we can $\vee$ eliminate to

9) | $\bot$

Which gives us the discharge by reductio of (2)

10) $¬(p \wedge q)$

Hope this helps you fill in the minimal gaps.

If you wanted to cheat you could have a look at de morgan's laws as you're going one way here, or ask whether you can prove this in all logics.

**Apologies** for my first attempt at formatting, I'll try to edit as I go

Comment: +1 Welcome! You're correct on the treatment of homework. You're not the first one having difficulty with natural deduction proofs: see [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10228/43351).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have graduated a long time ago so it is definitely not a homework. I am just studying some logic and found myself stuck with that problem.

Comment: Thanks Lord_Farin. What an agreeable and pleasant place! Good luck with the problem OP, I too graduated recently and miss it sorely!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same derivation (see Tom's answer), but it's in a different format, so might be of some tiny use to the OP:

[image]